# RewriteCond check static file existence

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to apply a RewriteRule only when one static, pre-determined file (`.redirect_enabled`) exists. [And yes I've simplified my usecase for SO] Is this possible? I've tried variations of the following:

```
RewriteCond /.redirect_enabled -f
RewriteRule .* /redirect_page.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I believe `-f` works with a complete filepath. Check what `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is when expanded and match that with your static file. You might be able to use `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`. (to test: do something like `RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar?rf=%{REQUEST_FILENAME}&dr=%{DOCUMENT_ROOT} [R,L]` and go to example.com/foo) Sadly can't test it on this computer.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly it. All it need was '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}' at the front. And great idea for testing!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond ... -f` requires a full filepath to test if a file exists. For dynamic files, `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` can be used. If you want to test for a static file, you'll need to mimic this format. `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` should point to the www-root of your website, so you can test the existance of a static file with something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}.redirect_enabled -f
RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [R,L]
```